# In my MacBook Pro one label called 'Password..' showing. How should I remove this permanently?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, password, screen

On my Macbook Pro, sometimes the password label appears on the screen. I closed all applications, but it did not go away and sits on the screen on top of all applications.

I need to restart the laptop to remove this, but it will reappear sometime later. Then also I've to do a restart to remove that label.

I've attached the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a systemic problem on Macs. I see leftover labels from Spotify and Mail all the time. Quitting the app that created the label usually fixes it though. I’m on macOS 10.14.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem happened to me. I tried closing the "FortiClient" app (from the menu bar) and reopening it and the label disappeared.

Comment: If the OP doesn't use FortiClient, what then?